# Bose condensation in degenerate states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, bose-einstein-condensate

Let us consider the condensation of non interacting bosons with a degenerate single particle ground state, so e.g. Spin-1 bosons without magnetic field. From thermodynamic arguments I would think that when the temperature is lowered below $T_C$ all degenerate states should be populated equally. My questions is now what kind of average are we taking?

Let's say we can measure in which of these states the macroscopic system is e.g. by looking at the polarization dependence of the absorption of photons coupling to a Spin-0 state. So we use something like dipole selection rules.

If we do this experiment once, will we see a polarization dependence, so that the system selects randomly one of these states to condense in or will we see no polarization dependence because these state are equally occupied in every run of the experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see no polarisation dependence, in that absorption of $\pi$ and $\sigma^\pm$ polarised light will occur at the same rate, hence not pointing at a prevalence of $m_F = 0$ or $m_F = \pm 1$.

In the absence of a magnetic field, the $m_F$ sub-levels are degenerate, hence the ground state will be a superposition of them:
$$ |\psi_0\rangle = \alpha |1\rangle + \beta |0\rangle + \gamma |-1\rangle, $$
and this ground state $|\psi_0\rangle$ will be the one that undergoes Bose-Einstein condensation. The particles, however, still need to be in one of $m_F = \{1,0,-1\}$, so they will need to Bose condense in their own single-particle state too. So you will end up with three Bose-Einstein condensates which, for non-interacting particles, are independent but whose critical temperature is the same, as this only depends on the background potential and number of atoms. You will end up with a *fragmented* BEC, where more than one single-particle state has macroscopic occupation.

If anything, the critical temperature $T_c$ will be *lower* that it would be for the same number of atoms in a single-state. In a uniform system, the critical temperature goes as $T_c \propto n^{2/3}$ where $n$ is the atomic density (hence $\propto N$, number of particles). For a BEC in each of the sub-levels, $ N\rightarrow N/3$ and hence $T_c \rightarrow (1/3)^{2/3}T_c$.

In all the above I have assumed that you have not specially prepared the system, so that the population is evenly distributed among sub-levels, since their statistical weight is the same. I.e. $\alpha = \beta = \gamma$.

Experimentally, of course, this would not be possible. You always have *some* interactions, which will cause some balance of population among sub-levels to have lower energy (for repulsvie interactions, in particular, it costs energy to have a fragmented BEC). You will also have spin-changing collisions that will release energy and eject particles from the trap. And background magnetic/electric fields will always lift the degeneracy of the $m_F$ states (magnetic fields between all of them, electric fields just depending on $|m_F|^2$).